# multisite not displaying thumbnail image after upload in nextgen gallery

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

Namaste,

https://www.gitamritam.com/2017y/inaug/

In the above link, its a multisite in wordpress, where thumbnails and gallery images are not showing up. We have done it using nextgen plugin which is really awesome in wordpress. But here its showing broken images in gallery.

We checked the same thing in a free hosting server and it works fine. Not sure why its not showing up in this multisite.

This is current url of image in multisite:
https://www.gitamritam.com/2017y/images/sites/18/gallery/17y-inaug/17gita-inaug-16.jpg

The subsite name ‘2017y’ is inserting in the image path, when we remove the multisite name from the image url its showing image.
https://www.gitamritam.com/images/sites/18/gallery/17y-inaug/17gita-inaug-16.jpg

Checked the same thing in another hosting server and it worked fine. Thumbnails are showing fine without removing subsite names, not broken.

Not sure why its not showing in gitamritam website.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks,
Editor – Gitamritam

Comment: Did you compare the htaccess between the servers? I think it's an mod_rewrite issue.

Comment: @jorin-van-vilsteren - Is it possible to check within wordpress dashboard, if its mod_rewrite itself using any plugins? Or to be specific, do you know the line to add in .htaccess???

Comment: I don't think it's possible, mod rewrite is a extra php module that is managing the URL rewriting from ugly urls with variables to pretty readable urls. If that's the problem, you should contact your hosting provider. You should check your htaccess file with an ftp client.

Comment: @jorin-van-vilsteren - We just checked it now, seems no changes with both. Is there anything else from your view which might be troublesome?

Comment: Maybe in your site settings. There should be a difference in your site URL and the Wordpress installation URL. The site is running at /2017y and the installation at /

Comment: @jorin-van-vilsteren - compared settings...seems no issue. Any other hint?

Comment: your images, did you upload them using NEXT GEN? or using the media uploader?

Comment: @David-Lee Using nextgen gallery Image upload

Comment: gitamritam.com using nginx as webserver, so there is difference way to handle the rewrite rule. Its not through .htaccess anymore, but in nginx site config.

The another hosting that working fine must be running apache as their web server.

If you have some custom htaccess rule, I suggest you to convert to nginx : https://winginx.com/en/htaccess

and or, save  permalinks in your wp-admin menu

Comment: Take look at this screenshot, is your gallery path was correct? 

https://i.imgur.com/OiDYMzj.png